# Displaying a "Score Board" in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am making an application for windows phone 8 that lets the user add fish types and angulars. They then pick which one they want to increment from a listpicker and can click and add or subtract button to increment its value. The types are stored in a Dictionary. I am trying to have a summary page that lists the fish and or angulars in descending order. Everything I have tried just shows repeated data.
for example the fish type is walleye and the user clicks + 3 times it shows

Walleye1

Walleye2

Walleye3

Instead of just

Walleye3

Here is my code so far

```
    Dictionary<string, int> FishListDic = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    Dictionary<string, int> AngularListDic = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    StringBuilder longlines = new StringBuilder();

private void FishAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FishListDic.ContainsKey(FishName.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fish is already in the list");
        }
        else
        {
            FishListDic.Add(FishName.Text, 0);
            Dictionary<string, int>.KeyCollection keyColl = FishListDic.Keys;
            FishList.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string s in keyColl)
            {                    
                FishList.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }

    private void FishIncrement_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string tempfishname;

        tempfishname = FishList.SelectedItem.ToString();
       // FishListDic[tempfishname] = ;
        int temp = fishcount;

        if (!FishListDic.ContainsKey(FishList.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        {
            FishListDic.Add(FishList.SelectedItem.ToString(), 0);
        }
        FishListDic[FishList.SelectedItem.ToString()]++;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in FishListDic)
        {   
            longlines.Append(kvp.Key.ToString() + kvp.Value.ToString() + '\n');
        }
        Summary_Fish.Text = longlines.ToString();
    }
```

Im pretty sure the problem is the stringbuilder append but i can't think of any other options at this point. I am trying to add it to a textblock on a pivot page as well. the above code only handles fish types so ill just duplicate for angulars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have such result because of:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in FishListDic)
{   
     longlines.Append(kvp.Key.ToString() + kvp.Value.ToString() + '\n');
}
```

For example:

Let's look the changes in your string step by step:
- string.Empty

- Walleye1
- Walleye1
  Walleye2

and so on..

You are accumulating `longlines`, but why do you need it?

Move `longlines` to the body of your function `FishIncrement_Click`. So it will be a new StringBuilder every time fish increments.

**p.s.**: just two remarks, maybe it will be useful for you:

1. If you replace `FishList.SelectedItem.ToString()` by `tempfishname`, your code become more clear.
2. If you want to add new line for your stringBuilder, you can use `AppendLine` method.

Comment: I was thinking of this solution last night laying in bed. Thanks a ton you convinced me I wasn't crazy and it worked. And good point on using the variable I had it in there but took it out for some reason thinking i was messing up another part.